# 僕は筧さんがずっと一途に思われてたじゃないですか。ああいうのとかが好きでした

Tags: particles, verbs

I was watching the first episode of Terrace House and got confused at something at the beginning.

> 1. 僕は筧さんがずっと一途に思われてたじゃないですか
> 2. ああいうのとかが好きでした

In the show a presenter is asked if anyone on the previous series of the show left an impression on him and he responds with 1 and 2. In 1, I'm having trouble understanding the sentence due to the use of the 思われる form and the が particle used with that.

Also in 2, is the の in ああいうのとか the placeholder の, as in the same の as 食べたのはこれです?

Comment: [This is a link to the script of the episode](https://pastebin.com/CMmzE8y4) The part im asking about is from 00:01:44,350 to  00:01:54,190, and is number 39 in the script

Answer (score 2):

It's more natural to interpret 思われる as the respectful form here.

You correctly understand の and ああいうの (one like that) indicates how 筧さんがずっと一途に思われていた (Kakei-san was always faithful).

The overall structure is 僕は…ああいうの とか が 好きでした: "I liked (one like) that or other things" with ああいうの explained as 筧さんが…じゃないですか "Kakei-san was always faithful, right?"